# Standard Hotkey to Close a Modal Window

Tags: modal-dialog, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am currently working on a project that features a great deal of modal popups and recently received some feedback from users requesting a hot-key or shortcut to close these modal windows.

I know that modal dialogs aren't really standardized across the board, so I was curious if anyone was aware of a commonly used hot-key or shortcut to implement this functionality.

**My question : Is anyone of aware of a commonly used shortcut or hot-key to close a modal popup? I am implementing it myself, but was just curious if anyone had any suggestions or recommendations on a choice.**

Comment: Instead of looking for a shortcut to close them, maybe you should be looking instead for a way not to display the modal windows in the first place?

Comment: They are intentionally being displayed - the user wanted a method to easily close the modals without having to click the Close button in the corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Escape</kbd> key is commonly used.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards - I just wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas. Thanks jdigital